# Magento : Upload .GIF image for a Product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-images

I want to upload .GIF image for a product in magento. it should be animated in product detail page. i have uploaded GIF image for a product but it's look like a .JPG/.JPEG image. it's extension is .GIF but not working in product detail page.

any help will be appreciate.

thanks

Answer (score -1):

The native Magento removes animation from GIF images while it resizes them for frontend. There are paid Magento extensions available to solve this purpose

Magento 1: https://redchamps.com/product-animated-gif-images-magento-1-extension.html

Magento 2: https://redchamps.com/product-animated-gif-images-magento-2-extension.html

Disclosure: Please note that these extensions belong to company RedChamps and I am the founder of the company.

Comment: no need of third party extension.